# React/Flux Architecture: Checking to Emit Change or componentShouldUpdate

Tags: reactjs, flux, reactjs-flux

Language: React 0.15.0^

State Management Choice: Flux

Are there times when it would be more logical/practical to just skip calling `emitChange` in a flux store(for example when no change occurred) - or is it always best stick with the convention of doing that type of checking in the `shouldComponentUpdate`. Thoughts?

Comment: you shouldn't ever need shouldComponentUpdate for data changes in a flux store. your components should register to changes emitted by a store or even a property on a store. they should always update when an emit change happens because the emit should only happen when the data in the store changes.

Comment: @JohnRuddell - I was thinking that since store are technically suppose to be immutable data only that all changes were suppose to be checked with ```this.state.something !== nextState.something```

Comment: few things, you dont need a store to manage local state info.. like the value inside an input. use your store to handle data from server requests and stuff like that. your components should have their own local state and that should be separate from other components that use the same store. that way you dont have duplication of values in multiple components.